# C# generic list as function parameter

Tags: c#, list

I am retrieving a list from a table in database:

```
var dependency = (from ctf in dc.Fields
                  join ctfd in dc.FieldsDependencies on ctf.id equals ctfd.Fieldid_depend
                  where ctf.ctid == ctid && ctf.fieldname == fieldname
                  select ctfd).ToList();
```

I am passing this list as parameter in another function:

```
public void DoYesDeleteDepField<T>(string fieldname, List<T> dep)
```

***How I can change it so I can retrieve the id field?***

But I cant iterate through the list and get the depsingle.id field.

```
foreach (var depsingle in dep)
        { var depsingleid = depsingle.id //ERROR
.....
```

Comment: Why is the function generic ? That's why you can't access specific type fields. T is generic and you're trying to access specific field in a specific type.

Comment: Did you mean `var desingleid = depsingle.id`?

Comment: yes @MotKohn thx

Comment: Well, `T` doesn´t know anything about an `id` or so, that´s why you get an error. You´d have to add a generic constraint to your type to allow only types that inherit from your base-class or implement your interface. Or simply omit generics when you´re interested in only one single type.

Comment: Look up inheritance

Comment: Any suggestions of how I can fix it?

Comment: You should post what the type of `ctfd` is as it seems to be your actual list-type as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what is T .. public void ... where T : IHasId
Or define it at class level

Comment: C# Programming Guide link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't know that the `<T>` has the parameter .id so either cast it (like this `var a = (int)something or var a = something as int`), or write it to something less generic from the `List<t>`. e.g. `List<classname>`.

Answer (score 0):

As `T` can be *anything* from `int` to `MyClass` there´s no member called `id` on all those types. Thus you need a generic constraint that tells the compiler what types are possible for `T`, e.g:

```
public void DoYesDeleteDepField<T>(string fieldname, List<T> dep) where T: MyClass
```

or omit generics completely as only one type is possible making the term *generic* quite useless. Simply define a class that hilds the values from your join and pass this to your method:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    // further properties
}
```

Now create instances of those objects from your query:

```
var result = (from ctf in dc.Fields
              join ctfd in dc.FieldsDependencies on ctf.id equals ctfd.Fieldid_depend
              where ctf.ctid == ctid && ctf.fieldname == fieldname
              select new MyClass 
              { 
                  id = ctf.id,
                  // further properties
              }).ToList();

public void DoYesDeleteDepField(string fieldname, List<MyClass> dep)
```